# Sketch the level curve in 2D

Tags: floats, asymptote

Sketch the level curve $f(x,y)=c$ with the following function with the indicated values of $c$.
$$f(x,y)=y^2-x^2; c=0,\pm1,\pm2$$
Please kindly help me to sketch this in latex sources.Thank in advanced.
[image: I sketch in Geogebra]

Comment: That is typical request "do-this-for-me! ... what you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. What have you tried so far? Do you want to import asymptote into latex?

Comment: Yes I want to import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) or http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
import contour;
import graph;
size(300);

typedef real newreal(real,real);

newreal f(real a){
  return new real(real x, real y){
    return y^2-x^2-a;
  };
}
/*
real F0(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2;}
real F1(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2-1;}
real F1_(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2+1;}
real F2(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2-2;}
real F2_(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2+2;}
*/
xaxis(xmin=-7,xmax=7,RightTicks(Step=2),Arrow);
yaxis(ymin=-7,ymax=7,LeftTicks(Step=2,modify=NoZero),Arrow);

real[] c=new real[]{0};

draw(contour(f(0),(-6,-6),(6,6),c),red+1bp);
draw(contour(f(1),(-6,-6),(6,6),c,111),green+1bp);
draw(contour(f(-1),(-6,-6),(6,6),c,123),blue+1bp);
draw(contour(f(2),(-6,-6),(6,6),c,134),orange+1bp);
draw(contour(f(-2),(-6,-6),(6,6),c,145),magenta+1bp);
```

[image]

Comment: I will explain if you have any questions about my code.

Comment: Ok really thank so much for your code.Now, I compile already.

Comment: Could you help me how to sketch this graph $f(x,y,z)=4x^2+4y^2-z^2$ in 3D? For range $-1<x,y,z<1$

Comment: @PetterGreen If you don't have any questions, done. For the second question, you should post a new question to show what you try so far and desired output.

Comment: Ok, I will post it

Comment: @Nhuyen Van Justonly Chi I posted.

Comment: a bit shorter code: `import contour;
unitsize(1cm);
real f(real x, real y){return y^2-x^2;}
real a=3;
pair A=(-a,-a), B=(a,a);
real[] c1={1,2}, c2={-1,-2}, c={0};
draw(contour(f,A,B,c,operator --));
draw(contour(f,A,B,c1,operator --),blue);
draw(contour(f,A,B,c2,operator --),red);
draw((-a,0)--(a,0),gray); label("$x$",(a,0),SW);
draw((0,-a)--(0,a),gray); label("$y$",(0,a),SW);`